# cin.get() ASCII code is different than ASCII code of already set char in code

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with `cin.get()`:

While getting a char, I am converting it to int, but when I enter it through console, the result is different than when its already set in code.

Here is example:

```
int ord(unsigned char chr){
    int ret=int(chr);
    return ret;
}
int main(){
    unsigned char chr='ň'; //This is my constant character 'ň' for now
    cout<<ord(chr)<<endl; //outputs : 242 ,which is alright for me, because it is same as in PHP and that I need
    chr=cin.get(); //now I change my constant character 'ň' to 'ň' written through console 
    cout<<ord(chr)<<endl; //outpus : 229 ,which is wrong for me, because its not same as in PHP 
}
```

How can I fix this?

I want to get 242, not 229, it must be same as ord()'s result in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The source file and the console input are going through two different processes to interpret the character and turn it into a code. The first is being entered into a text editor and converted by the compiler, the second is interpreted by the OS and console library.

The value 242 corresponds to the character in the [ISO/IEC 8859-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-2) or [Windows 1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) code page.

I'm not sure where the value 229 comes from, but almost certainly it's because a different code page is being used to assign a value to the character. Perhaps [code page 852](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852) for example.

Comment: I'd guess that the 229 character is from using OEM code page 852 in the console window.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, I just figured that out myself. It took a lot of trial and error. It makes sense that this would be used by a console window.

Comment: I tried this script to get what charset my application uses:
cout<<setlocale(LC_ALL,"")<<endl;
Result was: Slovak_Slovakia.1250 , so Windows 1250, and when I look that table of Win1250 codes, there is ň as 242, but my result is still 229 - cp852

Comment: @DieMeine, the encoding of the input is not determined by the C++ locale, it's determined by the Cmd window. There's a `chcp` command but I don't know how well it works.

Comment: Well, it works, but just partialy. When I change chcp to 1250, and I press "ň" on my keyboard, cin.get() outputs "˛", but when I mark and copy console ouput (˛) to here, it pastes ň :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your console is reading characters in from [code page 852](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852), where `ň` is encoded at code point 229 (0xE5), but you want its value in [ISO 8859-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-2) (aka Latin-2), where `ň` is encoded at code point 242 (0xF2).

I'd strongly suggest that you abandon this approach and work with Unicode exclusively, which doesn't have these types of issues.  Dealing with non-Unicode encodings such as the ISO 8859 variants and the DOS code pages is just asking for a world of headaches.

To use Unicode data, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207704/how-can-i-cin-and-cout-some-unicode-text).  In Unicode, `ň` is code point U+0148.

Also, this is not relevant to your problem, but your `ord()` function is useless.  `cin.get()` already returns an `int`, and `unsigned char` can be implicitly cast to an `int`.

Comment: I tried to use wstring and wchar_t as it was written there,so I replaced cout with wcout and cin with wcin, also added those headers, but result is still same - 229

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the character `ň` is not an ASCII character and therefore has no ASCII code.

Both PHP `ord()` and C++ `ord()` promise undefined results when given a character that is not ASCII.