# wcin is reading eof as default in C++ if input is redirected using standard redirection

Tags: c++, unicode

I have the following code in my console application

```
    std::cout << "\nEnter Id: ";
    std::cout.flush();
    std::wcin >> inId;

    std::cout << "\nEnter Secret: ";
    std::cout.flush();
    std::wcin >> inSecret;
```

If i read the input from console i am getting the correct input. But if i redirected the input from a text file them I am getting empty(EOF) value.
For MBCS it is working as expected.I couldn't figure out what is happening there in UNICODE. Can anyone help me on this? thanks in advance

Comment: What is the contents of the file you redirect from? What is its encoding?

Comment: file has the  following
  
  sam 
  xys27hdeo87


Encoding was utf-8

Comment: Maybe there's something here that gives you some ideas: [How can I cin and cout some unicode text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207704/how-can-i-cin-and-cout-some-unicode-text)

Comment: "*Encoding was utf-8*" - `std::wcin` can't read input in UTF-8. Use `std::cin` instead, or a separate `std::istream` that is attached to your platform's console API in binary mode, and then read in and convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16/32 yourself as needed (depending on the size of wchar_t). Which means you will have to first detect if STDIN is redirected and then read from it accordingly. Doing redirection detection is platform-specific, though, there is nothing in standard C++ to help with that.